# Python 3.6.2 - Finding the length of the longest string in a sublist and store that value in an existing list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm working through "Automate the Boring Stuff With Python." One of the projects wants me to:

a) create a list to store the length of the longest string in each sublist, colWidths.

b) find said length of the longest string in each sublist in the tableData list

c) store the length back into colWidths

Here's my code:

```
def printTable(alist):
    colWidths = [0] * len(alist)
    for i in alist:
       colWidths[i] = len(max(i, key=len))
       print(colWidths(i))


tableData = [['apples','oranges','cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
printTable(tableData)

#TODO: Make each list into a column that uses rjust(n) to justify all of 
#the strings to the right n characters
```

Whenever I run this code, I get this error on line 4:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Why can't I use colWidths[i] to take the result of len(max(i, key-len)) and store it in the respective colWidths value?

Comment: Basically, this: `colWidths[i]` `i` is not an index.

Comment: `i` is a list.  `some_list[another_list]` doesn't mean anything

Comment: When you use `for i in alist`, the data type of `i` is a list, not an integer. Python automatically assigns the data type in for statements. If you want to have i be an integer, you need to rewrite your for loop so the data type of `i` is an integer

Comment: @DeniseMoran more specifically, *variables aren't typed in Python at all*. Python for-loops just spit out *whatever* type of object is next in the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

A `for..in` loop uses the items stored in each index every iteration one-by-one. You're attempting to index a list with another list in this case, since `alist` is a 2-d list. What you want to do is `for i in range(len(alist)):` that way you're using numbers to index `colWidths` instead of an actual list, which is invalid.